# $Y$ has uniform distribution on [0,1], and conditional on Y = y, let X have a distribution of Bernoulli(y). What's P(Y|X=1)?

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

Using Baye's formula I have

$P(Y=y|X=1) = \frac{P(X=1|Y=y)*P(Y=y)}{P(X=1)}=\frac{y*1}{P(X=1)}$

Now
$P(X=1) = P(X=1|Y=0)P(=0)+P(X=1|Y=0.001)P(Y=0.001)+...P(X=1|Y=1)P(Y=1) = 0+0.001+0.002...+1 = \int_0^1{x}=1/2$

So $P(Y=y|X=1) = y / (1/2) = 2y$

But doesn't that mean $P(Y=0.6|X=1) = 2*0.6=1.2$? That doesn't seem to make sense since how can a probability be > 1?Could someone please tell me which step went wrong?

Comment: $X$ is discrete but $Y$ is continuous so you have to use probability density functions for $y$ instead of the probability expressions. Probability densities can be larger than 1.

Comment: Extending @GordonSmyth's comment a little -  try integrating $2y$ from $0$ to $1$, and you will see that the probability density function does integrate to $1$.

Comment: Its $f(y|X=x)$ and not $P(Y=y|X=x)$Note that Y cannot take a single value. It takes a range of values, eg $P(y<0.6|X=1) = 0.36$ etc

Comment: Of course. thank you everyone!